# Is there a way to change the fill of a Cell in a Bar Chart on Hover? - Recharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, recharts

I currently render the chart like this:

```
<BarChart width={868} height={40} data={data}
                    margin={{top:0, bottom: 10, left:0, right:0}} barSize={5}>
            <Tooltip
              labelStyle={{ textAlign: 'left' }}
               cursor={{fill: "blue"}}
      position={{ x: this.state.mouseX - 20, y:-5 }}
            />
            <Bar dataKey="blocks"
                 onMouseOver={e => this.getMouseX(e)} >
              {
                data.map((entry, index) => {

                  const result = entry.result >  4  ?  TRASH : NO_TRASH;
                  return <Cell fill={result} key={index}/>;
                })
              }
            </Bar>
          </BarChart>
```

Is there a way to change the cell/bar color, not cursor when you hover the bar?

Answer (score 2):

I used this [example](http://recharts.org/en-US/examples/BarChartWithCustomizedEvent) and changed the onClick to an onMouseOver event. Works fine.

Comment: I'm looking to do this but to base it off the same cursor mouseover as the tooltip - i.e. the mouse doesn't have to go over the bar itself, it can go higher up in the chart.

Comment: Found a solution here for what I was looking for: https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/1285#issuecomment-530494511